# I dropped the root user form mysql by mistake and then logged out. Nothing working!

Tags: mysql

I was trying to allow mysql login without sudo, as I was not logging in the mysql workbench, it said access denied. I tried some online debug, which asked me to drop the root user and add new root user, but unfortunately I pressed CTRL+Z and got logged out.

I tried skip grant tables thing, but I think there is no root user to which access can be granted.

I also tried uninstalling and installing everything but nothing works.

Is there anything to try fresh new or any remedy?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?